# negation of the statement "Suman is brilliant and dishonest if and only if Suman is rich"

Tags: propositional-calculus

Consider the following statements

> $P$ : Suman is brilliant.
>
> $Q$ : Suman is rich.
>
> $R$ : Suman is honest.

The negation of the statement,
"Suman is brilliant and dishonest if and only if Suman is rich" can be equivalently expressed as

> (1) $\sim Q\leftrightarrow \sim P \wedge R$
>
> (2) $\sim Q\leftrightarrow \sim P \vee R$
>
> (3) $\sim Q\leftrightarrow P \vee\sim  R$
>
> (4) $\sim Q\leftrightarrow P \wedge \sim  R$

**My Attempt:** I know that $\sim (A \leftrightarrow B) $ is equivalent to  $( A \wedge \sim B) \vee ( B \wedge \sim A)$. BUt it does not equate to any of the option. And It will be very lengthy if I go to find the truth table of all the options. Can anyone please help me how to handle this ?

I was trying to solve this by using Truth Table also. Can anyone please check if it is correct or wrong?

[image]

Comment: Recall that $A\land B$ is logically equivalent to $\neg(A\to\neg B)$.

Comment: I really can not get your hint..Can you please write an answer?@user170039

Comment: Use Truth Tables.

Answer (score 1):

> Suman is brilliant and dishonest if and only if Suman is rich

This statement can be expressed as $Q \leftrightarrow (P\cdot\overline R )$,

Negating this with the help of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916193/negation-of-biconditional-statements) question, we get $\overline Q \leftrightarrow (P\cdot\overline R )$ or $Q \leftrightarrow \overline{(P\cdot\overline R )} = Q \leftrightarrow (\overline P + R)$

The first expression above corresponds to option **(4)**, which is the answer.